# Undo breaks my addon

Tags: python, animation

I am writing addon, that adds keyframes to a group of objects at a time.

In example *.blend* file I created two objects: **Group_obj1** and **Group_obj2**.

If you select both of them and go to **View3D > Sidebar > View Tab > Group Poses** you can add keyframes to both of them when you hit **Add Keypose** button, both object will get keyframes by location at frame 1.

What I do next to break addon:

1. Go to frame 100. Hit button **Add Keypose**
2. Go to frame 150 and change Y location of one of the objects. Hit **Add Keypose**
3. Press **Ctrl+Z** so **keyframes in frame 150 are not set**.
4. Hit **Add Keypose** again and I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\out_exmpl\__init__.py", line 98, in execute
    GroupObjectsData.add_keypose(current_frame)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\addons\out_exmpl\__init__.py", line 27, in add_keypose
    x, y, z = obj.location
ReferenceError: StructRNA of type Object has been removed
```

How can I handle this Undo, so nothing breaks?

I want to keep all backend associated with inserting keyframes and other animation stuff in my own **class GroupObjects**, which is not inherrited from **bpy**.

My __init__.py: https://gist.github.com/spawly/3ceee6897519e74c3d3cddd3f96ef073

My .blend file with all objects added: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KlRZgFnQbrlKr349BMgAlxDyQM0--d8x/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Consider using a collection  of some prop group `obj : PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)` to keep reference to objects. Keeping a reference via list in some global class as you have done in addon is going to cause issues.

Comment: Thanks for the good input. I have no idea how to correctly use PointerPropety yet, but I will dive into that. So far I won't mark this question as resolved and will share if you advice worked for me